# How to edit local data for Kendo MVC Grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

As per documentation on Telerik's website for local binding of data:

Server - the widget performs server-side requests (HTTP GET) when doing paging, sorting and filtering.

Ajax - the widget will make Ajax requests when doing paging, sorting, filtering, grouping or ***saving data***.

Is this implying that there is currently no way to edit data locally with Kendo's MVC Grid?

My goal is to be able to edit the grid and then submit the whole page along with others part sof the model back to the server and save the data all together instead of making ajax calls for saving the data in the grid.

Using the below code I can get the grid to load, but editing the cells does not persist and when I go to past-back the page, the data is NOT bound the model.

```
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<LaborTimeViewModel>(Model.LaborTimes)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Procedure).ClientTemplate("#=Procedure ? Procedure.ProcedureDescription : ''#").EditorTemplateName("ProcedureEditor");
            columns.Bound(p => p.PerformedBy).ClientTemplate("#=PerformedBy ? PerformedBy.UserDescription : ''#").EditorTemplateName("UserEditor");
         columns.Bound(p => p.LaborTime).ClientTemplate("#if (LaborTime) {# #:kendo.toString(LaborTime.Hours, '00')#:#:kendo.toString(LaborTime.Minutes, '00')#:#:kendo.toString( '00')# #}#").EditorTemplateName("TimePickerEditor"); //.EditorTemplateName("NumericEditor");

        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .ServerOperation(false) 
            .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.WONumber);
                    model.Id(p => p.PerformedBy);
                    model.Id(p => p.TimerStart);
                })
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to work around the grid trying to save to a server.
First, Add and event for data bound on the grid builder.

```
.Events(events => events.DataBound("onGridDataBound"))
```

Then, add this javascript function for onGridDataBound

```
function onGridDataBound(e){
  //Prevent the grid from talking to the server
  var transport = e.sender.dataSource.transport;
  transport.create = function(e){e.success();}
  transport.destroy = function(e){e.success();}
  transport.update = function(e){e.success();}
}
```

By overriding the transport functions on the datasource, the grid will not try to make the Ajax calls, and the data saves to the grid's local model.

Ensure that the function is declared before the grid scripts run, either by using "DeferredScripts" or declaring the JS function before the grid in the page.